# SQL Server 2008 UPDATE Statement WHERE clause precedence

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause, operator-precedence

I wrote the following query:

```
UPDATE king_in
SET IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD = IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD + '3'
WHERE COALESCE(IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_TX, '') <> ''
        AND CHARINDEX('3', IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD) = 0
```

It checks to see if a field has a value in it and if it does it puts a 3 in a corresponding field if there isn't a 3 already in it.  When I ran it, I got a string or binary data will be truncated error.  The field is a VARCHAR(3) and there are rows in the table that already have 3 characters in them but the rows that I was actually doing the updating on via the WHERE filter had a MAX LEN of 2 so I was completely baffled as to why SQL Server was throwing me the truncation error.  So I changed my UPDATE statement to:

```
UPDATE king_in
SET IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD = k.IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD + '3'
FROM king_in k
        INNER JOIN
                     (
                        SELECT ki.row_key,
                                in_sqnc_nb
                        FROM king_in ki
                                INNER JOIN King_Ma km
                                    ON ki.Row_Key = km.Row_Key
                                INNER JOIN King_Recs kr
                                    ON km.doc_loc_nb = kr.ACK_ID
                        WHERE CHARINDEX('3', IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD) = 0
                                AND COALESCE(IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_TX, '') <> ''
                      ) a
            ON k.Row_Key = a.Row_Key 
                AND k.in_sqnc_nb = a.insr_sqnc_nb
```

and it works fine without error.

So it appears based on this that when doing an UPDATE statement without a FROM clause that SQL Server internally goes through and runs the SET statement before it filters the records based on the WHERE clause.  Thats why I was getting the truncation error, because even though the records I wanted to update were less than 3 characters, there were rows in the table that had 3 characters in that field and when it couldn't add a '3' to the end of one of those rows, it threw the error.

So after all of that, I've got a handful of questions.

> 1) Why?  Is there a specific DBMS reason that SQL Server wouldn't filter the result set before applying the SET statement?
>
> 2) Is this just a known thing about SQL that I never learned along the way?
>
> 3) Is there a setting in SQL Server to change this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - Likely because your criteria are not `SARG`able - that is, they can't use an index.  If the query optimizer determines it's faster to do a table scan, it'll go ahead and run on all the rows.  This is especially likely when you filter on a function applied to the field like you do here.

**2** - Yes.  The optimizer will do what it thinks it best.  You can get around this somewhat by using parentheses to force an evaluation order of your `WHERE` clause but in your example I don't think it would help since it forces a table scan regardless.

**3** - No, you need to alter your data or  your logic to allow indexes to be used.  If you **really really** need to filter on existence of a certain character in a field, it probably should be it's own column and/or you should normalize that particular bit of data better.

A workaround for  your particular instance would be to add a `WHERE LEN(IN_PNSN_ALL_TP_CNTRCT_CD) < 3` as well.

Comment: @tom - happy to help.  Stuff like this can be challenging sometimes when you expect SQL to do what you ask, not what it thinks is best :)